# Copied Netbeans IDE Maven Web project failes to compile

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, netbeans, maven

If I am going to make serious changes to my project I like to make a copy (right click project and select copy).

I have created copies of my projects many times (maven web applications included) without issue.

Now all I do is copy the project making no changes, leaving the copy settings on default (project name etc) and then try to run it and spring decides to take issue with it. Again I try running the original and it works. I deleted the faulty copy, restarted and tried again and still it does not work.

Here are my maven/system details:

```
 Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-4)
 Java version: 1.6.0_20
 Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
 Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: UTF-8
 OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.35-23-generic" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
```

Here is the exception:

```
INFO: 2010-12-21 16:08:23,715 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext:215 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of persistence methods failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/DataSourceLookup
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:998)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4664)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5266)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/DataSourceLookup
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:682)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:614)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:143)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:503)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:473)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:599)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectMethods(InjectionMetadata.java:117)

INFO:         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/DataSourceLookup
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2406)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2716)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2002)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:959)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
    ... 77 more

SEVERE: PWC1306: Startup of context /quickstart_upgrade-0.1-SNAPSHOT failed due to previous errors
SEVERE: PWC1305: Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: PWC2769: Manager has not yet been started
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5456)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5284)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of persistence methods failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/DataSourceLookup
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5289)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of persistence methods failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/DataSourceLookup
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:998)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4664)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5266)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/DataSourceLookup
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:682)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:614)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:143)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:503)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:473)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:599)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectMethods(InjectionMetadata.java:117)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/DataSourceLookup
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2406)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2716)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2002)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:959)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
    ... 77 more
```

Comment: Please share your persistence file, applicationContext and web.xml. Also ServletContextListener if any...

Comment: I ran the diff command against the source directories... there was no difference, so I expanded it to recursively compare all files under the whole project tree to the other project. It found differences in the target folder, there were a number of jars not in the other.  This is because I kept rebuilding the project, with no clean in between.  So when I cleaned the original project it to had the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it does not look like a compilation error.  The error seems to be running the application.

Secondly, based on the stacktrace, it looks like `spring-jdbc` related jar is missing. Perhaps  you can check your Netbeans/maven configuration related to this.

Comment: It was exactly as you said spring-jdbc was missing.  What I couldn't get my head around last night was why one project was running and the copy was not, the answer was that the copy was built from scratch while the original has the same issue but it would not be exposed until it was cleaned.